# Strange outcome of a "review audit"

Tags: support, review, disputed-review-audits

There are sometimes audits when doing reviews on MSE, and I perfectly agree with that.

It's my understanding that usually, people who ask questions should show what they have tried to tackle the problem, so that MSE is not just a *"do my homework for free"* site. Questions that do not satisfy this minimum ought to be closed.

I have just come across this audit, that puzzles me. The question comes from here: [Does $A^{-1}A=G$ imply that $AA^{-1}=G$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1696115/does-a-1a-g-imply-that-aa-1-g)

Do I have to reevaluate my understanding of what is expected in questions?

[image]

To be clear: I understand that the question is not trivial and may be very interesting, but I think it's irrelevant to [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960).

---

Another funny one: getting a "STOP!" because I have written a **comment** to a high quality post. The review machine looks drunk.
I agree with the comment of Lord_Farin below, yet it's strange to get such messages for no apparent reason.

Comment: Bottom line: if your intention is good, ignore failed audits.

Comment: What the others said. If I had the power to handpick questions used as review audits, this question would most certainly not make the cut. A good question masquerading as a bad question would trip many honest reviewers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is "missing context," as such it can be voted to be closed within the policies of the site (even if not everybody agrees with this policy).

However, sometimes question that are interesting or unusual can be well received even without context. Abstractly, not few are of the opinion that unusually positive aspects in a question can compensate for lack of context or other negatives. Differently, lack of context or not following other recommendations in the linked post are not each a knock-out criterion, but rather they guide an evaluation of the question-post in total.

In the present case, I think what made the question so popular was the "That's obviously true. Wait, no, it's not obvious. It's false!" type of surprise one can have with it.

Given this, I think this is just a corner case that is likely to trip one up in a review.